# styled-components: How to prevent props from being sent down to Link component?

Tags: react-router-dom, styled-components

I am using styled components to style my links. I also need to sometimes use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Anchor } from './src';

export const StyledLink = Anchor.withComponent(Link);
```

However, the above code produces the following warning in the console:

> Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `unstyled`.
>
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead:
>   unstyled="true" or unstyled={value.toString()}.

`unstyled` is a prop that is being passed to `StyledLink` like so:

```
<StyledLink unstyled />
```

This warning is generated by the `Link` component and is because the `unstyled` prop is being passed down to the DOM element by `Link`.

So, the question is, how to prevent `Link` from trying to add props to the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `Styled Component` is to serve a transparent component with original props (ref: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props).
The pattern you are looking for is a `HoC` (ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that returns a styled (or not-styled, based on props) component.

Comment: So how do I strip out certain props before they get to `Link`?

Comment: When a component is not a simple element all props are passed down. If you return component from a HoC you can choose which props to pass down and which props top process at HoC-level

Answer (score 0):

Mosè Raguzzini is right.  A solution you might want to try is to create a small custom component that uses styled components to wrap around the Link component that will pass the necessary props to your styled component, and also the Link component

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem right. I use the solution provided on the official documentation page https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript

inside styles.ts file

`export const StyledLink = styled(({ hoverColor, color, ...rest }) => React.createElement(Link, rest))<{
  hoverColor?: string;
  color?: string;
}>...`

or inside style.tsx

`export const StyledLink = styled(({ hoverColor, color, ...rest }) => <Link {...rest} />)<{
  hoverColor?: string;
  color?: string;
}>...`

The same approach should work for ES6 just remove types.

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar today, where I had to strip the custom prop that I was passing down to the styled component to genearte a conditional CSS. **I was working with styled-components and semantic-ui-react**:

```
const TableHeaderCell = styled(({ hasBorderLeft, ...rest }) => <Table.HeaderCell {...rest} />)`
  border-left: ${hasBorderLeft => (hasBorderLeft ? 'none' : '')};
`;
```

And I got rid of react warnings for unknown props. Using it like:

```
<TableHeaderCell hasBorderLeft={hasBorderLeft} />
```